# Intuition for symbols and equality

Tags: real-analysis, logic, notation, intuition

The equality symbol is used everyday and according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)) or [this answer on stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347569/explaining-the-meaning-of-equality) the view appears to be that we have a distinction between symbols and objects. Symbols are the things we can write down such as $x,S,\mathbb{R} (...)$ and objects are the things they refer to (their "value"). We can have different symbols refering to the same object, in which case one can connect them with the equality symbol "$=$" and say that their values are equal (since they are the same object). A simple case should be an equality by definition, in which we introduce a new symbol to refer to the object that the symbol on the right refers to: $$A:=B,$$ where $B$ has already been introduced, or a more concrete case $$2n:=n+n, \ A\cap B:=\{x \ | \ x \in A \wedge x \in B\},$$ assuming the symbols on the RHS already refer to certain objects.

Another common type of symbols one introduces is the addition "$+$" which is used in many contexts, e.g. in the context of the "usual" number systems. Strictly speaking this should be a symbol of the following type. Assume that $X,Y$ are sets and that $f:X \to Y$ is a function. Then we define $f(x)$ to be the unique $y \in Y$ that  satisfies $(x,y) \in f$, that is $$f(x):=y, \mathrm{where}\ (x,y)\in f.$$ In this case we introduce the notation $n+m:=+(n,m)$ to simplify notation.

Coming back to improving the intuition, a common theorem of calculus is that $$\int_{a}^b f(x)dx = \int_{a}^c f(x)dx+\int_{c}^b f(x)dx$$ assuming the necessary conditions for $f$ and $c \in [a,b]$. So what does this mean intuitively? It means that the object the LHS refers to is the same as the image of the integrals on the right under the addition function. That is, it is the unique $y$ that satisfies $$\left(\left(\int_a^c f(x)dx,\int_c^b f(x)dx\right),y \right) \in +$$

**My questions are:** $(1)$ Is what I wrote above correct?

$(2)$ What is your intuition for equality? Is my intuition "good"? I didn't think much about it when working with it previously, but now that I do I realized that I can learn a ton regarding the intuition of it.

I found it quite confusing at first, when thinking more about it, that different symbols can refer to the same objects. But I guess a simple way to see this is that objects can have different names anywhere, and it is not the name but the properties the objects have and what they "are", that is important. Although as far as I know, the last part is not answered in mathematics.

Comment: Maybe useful the post [Does the sentence "prove that two things are equal" has a sense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4165338/does-the-sentence-prove-that-two-things-are-equal-has-a-sense)

Comment: See also [Math philosophy:about arithmetic operations and equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546194/math-philosophyabout-arithmetic-operations-and-equality): we can summarize the mathematical theory of *equality* in the following way: $1+1=2$ means that the two *expressions* "$1+1$" and "$2$" are two *names* for the same (mathematical) *object*: the number *two*.

Comment: The questions you have been asking recently are all related to the division of syntax and semantics, which is central to mathematical logic and model theory in particular. I recommend reading the first two chapters of  of the book *A Shorter Model Theory* by Wilfred Hodges for an illuminating discussion of these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you said is correct. To make this answer not embarrassingly short, I'll make an additional point.

While the symbols are what they are, we can often attribute meaning to them. To take your integral example, [morally](http://eugeniacheng.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cheng-morality.pdf), it says that the are under the curve of $f$ between $a$ and $b$ is the same as the area under the curve between $a$ and $c$ summed with the area under the curve between $c$ and $b$.

This is typically "insightful" as a consequence of how human cognition works. So while we can look at it symbolically and leave it at that, that's not usually what mathematicians are trying to do.

Equality (not just equality, but other comparisons and also completely different kinds of statements) allows us to have these insights (or as [platonists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics/) would have it, to look into the very real mathematical world).

That we use different symbols to refer to the same object is a consequence of the language we use to talk about mathematics together our own cognition.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I would appreciate if you could elaborate more as to why we use different symbols for the same thing. I appear to somewhat struggle with this.

Comment: That heavily relates to the insight I mentioned in the answer. We don't know they're different things to start with, we discover they are. Say, in the example of the symbols $1 + 1$ and $2$, we don't know at the first that they refer to the same object. We have an understanding of $1$, $+$ (and consequently of $1 + 1$), we have an understanding $2$ and we get the insight that they refer to the same object, but we don't really know beforehand.